# how can print value of other table in a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on asp .net mvc3. My database is SQL Server and I'm using the ado.net database access mechanism.

this is my action in controller:

```
public ViewResult ProductIndex()
{                
    return View(db.Product.ToList());
}
```

and this is my ProductIndex.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<CalcoWOMS.Models.Product>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCategoryID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductUsageID) 

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductRangeID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
}
```

My problem is that I want to display the value of the "Description" field in the "ProductCategory" Table, not the ProductCategoryID field, in the first line of my ProductIndex.cshtml.  How should I modify the controller and view (.cshtml file)?

this is my product table:
[image]

this is my productCategory table from which I want to access code
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does your model have navigation properties?

if so, this should work (where `ProductCategory` is the navigation property):

`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCategory.Description)`

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it is working very well for your  above line for ProductCategory Table, similar way i want to use this line for ProductRange Table but sir there is still a problem is that when i write @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductRange.Description)   then error is occured that "CalcoWOMS.Models.Product does not contains defination for ProductRange".